# Scheduled icon using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create icon like following using css. But, it looks very tough.

I tried [this](https://jsfiddle.net/b1ed2zg9/) thing but doesn't looks good.

[image]

```css
.schedule {
height: 10px;
width: 10px;
position: relative;
}

.oval { 
    height: 10px; 
    width: 10px; 
    background-color: #FDD13A;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.line { 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    height: 5.97px; 
    width: 4.08px; 
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5px;
    left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="schedule">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="oval"></div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use fontawesome https://fontawesome.com/icons/clock?style=solid

Comment: I agree, if you want some cool icons, just use fontawesome, the best one so far for that kind of things...and very very easy to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `transform and position:absolute` make responsive

```css
.cancelled {
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
position: relative;
background-color: #FDD13A;
border-radius: 50%;
}

.cancelled2 {
height: 500px;
width: 500px;
position: relative;
background-color: #FDD13A;
border-radius: 50%;
}

.line1 { 
    position:absolute;
    width:10%;
    height:40%;
    top:10%;
    left:45%;
    background:#ffffff;}

.line2 { 
    position:absolute;
    width:10%;
    height:40%;
    top:50%;
    left:45%;
    background:#ffffff;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="cancelled">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
</div>

<div class="cancelled2">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not responsive at all. The parent element has fixed size.

Comment: @mahan just change size of parent element and no need to change of others...

Answer (score 1):

Font awesome, as mentioned in the comments, is always a nice way to go in these cases if you can use it. That being said if you are curious to do it own your own, you can try something like this:

```css
body {
  background: #4c4c4c;
}

.schedule {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: orange;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.line1,
.line2 {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 10px;
}

.line1 {
  top: 8px;
  left: 6px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.line2 {
  top: 15px;
  left: 9px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="schedule">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `clock` from [feather-icon](https://feathericons.com/?query=clock). You can download only the icons you need. In this case, you can download only `clock` - a simple svg file.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clock">
  <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10" fill="orange" stroke="orange"/>
  <polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14" fill="none" stroke="white"/>
</svg>
```

2. Use CSS [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) after and before.

```css
.clock {
  position:relative;
  border-radius:50%;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background: orange;
  position:relative;
}

.clock:before,
.clock:after {
  position:absolute;
  width: 4px;
  height:20px;
  display:block;
  background: #fff;
  content:'';
  left:22px;
  
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.clock:after {
  top:7px;
}

.clock:before {
  top:5px;
  transform: rotate(120deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="clock"></div>
```

---

If you use the icon along with text, it is best to use relative unit `rem` rather than `px` or `%`.

```css
html {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.clock {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
}

.clock:before,
.clock:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.2rem;
  height: 1rem;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  left: 1.4rem;
  border-radius: 0.1rem;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.clock:after {
  top: 0.6rem;
}

.clock:before {
  top: 0.5rem;
  transform: rotate(120deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="clock"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure CSS3 solution.

Not sure why you inserted only one line with `.oval`, but you will need two.

Just rotate other line with `transform-origin` and `rotate`.

```css
.cancelled {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.oval { 
    height: 20px; 
    width: 20px; 
    background-color: #FDD13A;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.line-1 {
    height: 11px;
    width: 3px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;
}
.line-2 {
    height: 10px;
    width: 3px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: rotate(-70deg);
    border-radius:0 0 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cancelled">
  <div class="oval">
    <div class="line-1"></div>
    <div class="line-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure SVG. Scalable and accepted by all major browsers without needing to download a library

```html
<svg width="580" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
  <title>background</title>
  <rect fill="#fff" id="canvas_background" height="402" width="582" y="-1" x="-1"/>
  <g display="none" overflow="visible" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="canvasGrid">
   <rect fill="url(#gridpattern)" stroke-width="0" y="0" x="0" height="100%" width="100%"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <ellipse ry="123.5" rx="123.5" id="svg_1" cy="190.953125" cx="295" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#ffffff" fill="#ffff00"/>
  <rect stroke="#ffffff" id="svg_2" height="105.999996" width="18" y="99.453129" x="283.5" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#ffffff"/>
  <rect transform="rotate(24.084814071655273 331.9999999999999,221.45312500000003) " stroke="#ffffff" id="svg_3" height="16" width="100.999998" y="213.453125" x="281.5" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#ffffff"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I think it is unnecessary to use so many elements. Use just circle and polylines :)

Comment: @mahan just a proof of concept. I'm not an SVG expert

Answer (score 0):

It has been adding icons in this way, logos and other elements for quite some time. If I want to add another icon, I just need to add the next symbol to the parent element. Works even in old IE. For this you can color as you want, change the size without loss of quality because it is svg;)

```css
.scheduled-icon {
  fill: orange;
}
   
.hand-of-a-clock {
  stroke: #fff;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
  <symbol id="scheduled-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10" />
    <path class="hand-of-a-clock" fill="none" d="M12 6v6l4 2" />
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="share__icon scheduled-icon">
  <use xlink:href="#scheduled-icon"></use>
</svg>
```